# Android - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I getting a NoClassDefFoundError due to this line of code:

```
adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
```

I'm thinking it maybe an issue with my ResponseListener() method but I can't find anything wrong with it.  Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Adapter initialization
    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, adapter));

    // Welcome Message
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textview.setText("Use SocialAuth by creating your own UI.");
    textview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textview.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 0);
}

// To receive the response after authentication
private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Successful");

        // Changing Sign In Text to Sign Out
        // Code to refresh Single ListView Item : You can remove it for your
        // app
        View v = listview.getChildAt(pos
                - listview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        TextView pText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.signstatus);
        pText.setText("Sign Out");

        // Get the provider
        final String providerName = values
                .getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "providername = " + providerName);

        int res = getResources().getIdentifier(providerName + "_array",
                "array", CustomUI.this.getPackageName());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomUI.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select Options");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more);

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                CustomUI.this, R.layout.provider_options, getResources()
                        .getStringArray(res)), 0,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        Events(item, providerName);
                    }
                });
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Error");
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        Log.d("Custom-UI", "Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");

    }
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.socialauth.customui.CustomUI.onCreate(CustomUI.java:70)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-20 16:21:44.562: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a jar in your classpath that contains this `org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter` class?

Comment: Maybe this can help http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=4

Comment: I saw that ticket already.  I have the latest jar files in my libs folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error relates to the issue if the DVM is not able to find the class file at runtime. Meaning it is not contained within your apk file.

I am assuming the jar file that contains the SocialAuthAdapter class that you are using is contained within your lib folder and not libs folder. So move the jar file to libs folder and then recompile the apk file.